# Plot multiple curves in the same plot in R

Tags: r, plot, curve

I want to plot 3 curves in the same plot:

```
curve(dweibull(x, shape=0.5, scale = 1), from=0, to=5)
par(new=TRUE)
curve(dweibull(x, shape=1, scale = 1), from=0, to=5)
par(new=TRUE)
curve(dweibull(x, shape=1.5, scale = 1), from=0, to=5)
```

I am aware that using `par(new=TRUE)` will plot the curves in the same plot but I had three y-axes smeared together, as below:
[image]

How do I get one clear y-axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `ggplot` option using `geom_function` like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot() + 
  geom_function(fun = function(x) sin(x)) +
  geom_function(fun = function(x) cos(x)) +
  geom_function(fun = function(x) 3*x) +
  labs(x = "x", y = "y") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Use `add=TRUE` as shown below:

```
curve(dweibull(x, shape=0.5, scale = 1), from=0, to=5)
par(new=TRUE)
curve(dweibull(x, shape=1, scale = 1), from=0, to=5,  add=TRUE)
par(new=TRUE)
curve(dweibull(x, shape=1.5, scale = 1), from=0, to=5, add=TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: `from=0, to=5` is only needed once, repetition superfluous. Also the `par(new=TRUE)`s aren't needed.